# can't find referenced method in class with Proguard

Tags: java, servlets, proguard

when i execute obfuscation using proguard i get this error :

> can't find referenced method 'javax.servlet.servletContext
>   getServletContext()' in class
>   javax.servlet.http.httpServletRequest

i tried to include the servlet-api from tomcat7 , but still the same problem .
any help ?

Comment: Is this an exact copypaste of the error message? The class part looks wrong. The method part looks by the way also strange, after all, I'd expect `javax.servlet.servletContext` to be `javax.servlet.ServletContext` instead.

Comment: sorry i messed up the class name . i edited my message above.

Comment: Ignoring your lowercase/uppercase typos in the error message, this can only mean that ProGuard is somehow using Servlet 2.5 or older in the classpath. This method was introduced in Servlet 3.0. So the concrete problem is in ProGuard setup/configuration. Sorry, I can't answer this problem from top of head as I haven't really used it extensively. Good luck.

Comment: your answer was more than enough , i deleted servlet-api-2.5-6.1.9.jar from my proguard config and added servlet-api.jar from tomcat7 .. it worked just fine thanks (if you don't mind posting your answer so that i can check it )

Comment: Okay, I reposted this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring your lowercase/uppercase typos in the error message, this can only mean that ProGuard is somehow using Servlet 2.5 or older in the classpath. This method was [introduced](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServletContext%28%29) in Servlet 3.0. So the concrete problem is in ProGuard setup/configuration. You'd need to remove any Servlet 2.5-or-older libraries from ProGuard's setup and add a Servlet 3.0 compatible one.