# can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String lookupNamespaceURI(java.lang.String)' in class org.w3c.dom.Node

Tags: proguard

I was successfully using proguard 4.5.1 with proguard-maven-plugin (no version specified) to obfuscate my webapp on JDK 6 platform.

When I upgraded to JDK 7 platform I had to upgrade to proguard 4.8 with proguard-maven-plugin 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT I get two instances of the following warning during execution of proguard which cause the build to fail:

```
 [proguard] Warning: mypackage.MyClass: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String lookupNamespaceURI(java.lang.String)' in class org.w3c.dom.Node
```

I have checked an made sure that .../jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/rt.jar is being specified as library:

```
[proguard] Reading library jar [.../jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/rt.jar]
```

I am getting the following warning that is likely related to my problem:

```
[proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.w3c.dom.Node]
```

A similar issue was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283581/cant-find-referenced-method-in-class-with-proguard) but it does not help me resolve my issue.

Any tips on how I can find out which library has the duplicate definition(s) and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was resolved when I removed the following unused dependency from my project:

```
 +- org.swinglabs:swingx-ws:jar:1.0:compile
|  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:compile
|  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile
```

The way I debugged the source of the problem was as follows.

1. I looked for the first warning "duplicate definition of library class [org.w3c.dom.Node]" which is the class mentioned in the original warning message.
2. Next I searched backwards for "Reading library jar " to see which jar had the duplicate definition. It was xml-apis-1.3.03.jar
3. Then I ran maven's depenency:tree goal on the project to see which jar pulled in the xml-apis-1.3.03.jar dependency. It was swingx-ws jar.

The swingx-ws jar was added recently to the project was thankfully was never actually used. So all I had to do was remove it. If I really had to use that jar I suspect I could exclude the xml-apis dependency and still make things work.